# UITableViewController won't scroll if keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, uitableview

I have some TableViewController with static Cells and some TextFields. A few Days ago, everything works fine, the TableViewController managed the "scroll to cell if keyboard appear", the contentOffset, etc. and I don't had to use `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:...]` or something else.

But today I notice that the Table won't set the contentOffset and scroll. I don't know what or where I changed something to cause this behavior, I just added some Labels and change origins.

So, how is it possible to activate/deactivate the automatically scroll to cell, if the keyboard appear?

Or maybe the Storyboardfile is broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Problem.

I added `viewWillDisappear`, but without `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` the TableViewController won't scroll, etc.